# Performance issue: Data importing in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I am using **MySQL v5.1**.

My simple scenario is that I would like to **import a large amount of data** from a table in one database to another table in another database. And the table in another database (to where the data is going to be inserted) will be truncated first.

To be detailed, Say I have two databases, named '**db_one**' and '**db_two**' respectively.

**db_one** has a table named `db_one_cars` which contains **6,000,000 records** (which is a big amount of data). While **db_two** has a table named `db_two_cars` which contains also a big amount of data.

I am going to firstly remove all the data in `db_two_cars` (truncate the table), then **import all the data from** `db_one_cars` **to** `db_two_cars`. (Note: the two tables are in two databases respectively).

So, I created a sql file with content like following:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE db_two_cars;

ALTER TABLE db_two_cars DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO db_two_cars  (car_id, name, customer, company_name)
SELECT id, CONCAT('c-', name), customer, company_name FROM db_one.db_one_cars;

ALTER TABLE db_two_cars ENABLE KEYS;
```

both **db_one_cars** and **db_two_cars** tables are InnoDB table and have the same structure, `car_id` is used as `primary key`, `company_name` is used as `multi-column key`, `customer` is used as `multi-column key`.

I would like to **speed up** this large amount of data importing, and also want a **good performance** to query the table after improting data.

**my questions:**

1. Is it needed to have `OPTIMIZE TABLE db_two_cars` at the end of my SQL statement? and why? (will it improve the performance? I am merely inserting data)
2. Do I need to use `ALTER TABLE db_two_cars PACK_KEYS = 0 ?` and why? (will it improve the performance)
3. What other things can I do to improve the speed and future query performance?

**P.S.** The performance I mean includes speed up the data importing and good performance for future data querying

Answer (score 1):

to improve this do export of the data to csv file

and load this file to the new table using :

[load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

another tips to speed this u can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463602/mysql-load-data-infile-acceleration)

Comment: You mean load data infile is much faster than the way I used? How to deal with the indexes then?

Comment: about the dealing with index see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827445/what-mysql-settings-affect-the-speed-of-load-data-infile

Comment: I am still interested about my 1st and 2nd questions though load data infile could be a good option. If anyone can provide also an answer of my first 2 questions.